# How to fix GATTTools GLib-WARNING **: Invalid file descriptor

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, gatt

```
gatttool -b 00:E0:4C:EF:9D:52 --interactive 
[00:E0:4C:EF:9D:52][LE]> connect 
Attempting to connect to 00:E0:4C:EF:9D:52 
Connection successful 
[00:E0:4C:EF:9D:52][LE]> 
(gatttool:1446): GLib-WARNING **: Invalid file descriptor.
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see link below for the most detailed explanation of this warning I managed to find so far:

http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg67617.html

In short: it is due to redundant calls to g_io_channel_unref, g_io_channel_shutdown inside gatttool code.

Glib IO socket created inside btio/btio.c:create_io has internal IO channel reference counter, and when it reaches zero object will be disposed automagically. And this is what indeed happening inside chain of calls starting form attrib/interactive.c:disconnect_io. But later there are two calls: g_io_channel_unref, g_io_channel_shutdown that are redundant because socket were already closed before.

This link contains a patch attached by an author that removes last two redundant calls. So you can recompile gatttool yourself and get rid of the warning, but as you can see it is not a critical one and should not cause any major issues.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Hello @Gennadii Kurabko, I read your post and the link you posted. However. I don't see the patch attached by an author. Could you please tell me where can I find it ? Thanks

Comment: @S7_0, when you scroll down to the bottom you will find diff provided by the author: